# Chatbot to give information on staff

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've created a bot that allows users to ask about a specific staff in the company I work for. E.g. "who is John Smith?" the bot will then reply, John Smith is xxxx.

Currently I have entered about 10 individuals from the company, using 10 different intents, e.g. Who is Staff 1, Who is staff 2 etc etc. the first one I entered is called Raymond.

If a user enters "Who is" followed by a name that doesn't exist as one of the 10, it automatically defaults to assuming they are asking Raymond, instead I would like the bot to say "sorry that person doesn't work for this company".

Can you give me pointers?

Thanks
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

We can provide a autocomplete facility rather than showing a error message. Firstly, this will allow user to see the staff data which is available. And secondly, it will stop the unnecessary hits to the database in case, the user types in some name which doesn't exist. There are many autocomplete widgets available online such as

[autocomplete-jquery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)